# ros2 bag record Regex

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to record certain topics using `ros2 bag record -a`. The topics have different namespaces: /uuid21, /uuid22 and /uuid23. How do I select one namespace?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391761/ros2-bag-record-regex/) by [fnax8902](https://answers.ros.org/users/73234/fnax8902/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I typically use a launch file with the following:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="rosbag_record_sensors" output="screen"
      args="--buffsize=0 
            -e '(.*)you_want_this(.*)|(.*)and_this(.*)'
            -x '(.*)you_dont_want_this(.*)|(.*)neither_that(.*)'"/>
```

Separation is done using `|`.

---

Originally posted by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) with karma: 212 on 2021-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2